# Grass seed for shade

Tags: grass

I live in northeast

I have a yard in which each section gets about 2 hours of direct sunlight.

Is there a "total shade" grass seed?  Can't find one at the HD stores.

I've tried sun/shade mixes and low water, etc.

Grass just doesn't do well here

Moss, however, does

Comment: Is the lawn shady because of a building? A large tree? Many large trees? If the shade is from a tree or trees, do you know what kind of tree(s)?

Comment: @Jurp building?-Yes.  Many large trees?-Yes.  80% white pine, 20% oak

Comment: @Jurp Past 2pm, as sun is heading west, the shade begins to lengthen due to trees.  At 8am, building covers 60% of the yard.

Comment: Here is a shade-specific lawn seed from a company local to me (Pacific NW): https://ptlawnseed.com/collections/conventional-lawn-seed-mixes/products/super-shade-supplement.

Answer (score 2):

Check local people for advice. In Melbourne (Australia) the grass to use is Red Fescue. Looks like thin green wire, and needs frequent reseeding if you want the lush look.

Answer (score 0):

Certain species of fescue grass (like "sheep", "chewing" and "strong creeping red" fescue) grow very well in shade. Here's an example of a seed mix designed to grow well in shaded areas:

https://icanlawn.com/shade-supreme-lawn